# Is there any way to "hide" null elements in an Array?

Tags: java

I'm creating table like this:

```
String[5] tab;
```

and want the user to fill the table with some Strings.
Before that table has 5 `null`s and my question is:

How can I hide these null's from `System.out.println(tab[x])`?

Adding code

```
public class Main {
public static void main ( String[] args ){

    String[] tab = new String[5];

    System.out.println("showing tab: ");
        for(int i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
            System.out.println(tab[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code. Using ``println`` on an array does not even show you the contents without further work.

Comment: `Arrays.fill(tab, "");`

Comment: Or `String[5] tab = { "", "", "", "", "" };`

Comment: if (tab[i]!=null){System.out.println(tab[i])}

Comment: `String[5] tab;` is not a valid array declaration syntactically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you want to print them before user fills it in:

```
String[] tab = new String[5];
Java.util.Arrays.fill(tab, "");
System.out.println("showing tab: ");
    for(int i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
        System.out.println(tab[i]);
}
```

You should know that when doing this, your String array will have a empty string (of length 0) in each cell.

Or if You are asking to just "hide" them when you print them after user fills in the String array? For that you can do this:

```
//Lets say your String array has this content after 
//user fills it: {"test1", "", "test2", "test4", "", null}

for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
     if(!(tab[i] == null)){
         System.out.println(tab[i]);
     }      
}
```

It will print everything but `null`

Comment: Thank you sir! Works like charm!

Comment: i accepted and upvoted but im rookie here and still need 15 rep so my votes can change publicly score.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize the array.  There are several methods.  Here is one:

```
String[] tab = { "", "", "", "", "" };
```

Comment: would it even compile? would it not give an error at [5]? Try to initialize it in IDE and see what happens. I tried it and it gave me an error.

Comment: Yeah, you don't want the 5 -- I blindly copied that from the OP's question.